# getaddrinfo без кеширования

Tags: c++, winapi

1)Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать getaddrinfo(), чтобы функция не смотрела локальный кеш ранее сохраненных IP-адресов ?

Просто получается так, я отключаю интернет, а функцию getaddrinfo все равно выдает данные, как то это неправильно.

2)И попутно тогда вопрос в эту же тему: а что, если getaddrinfo() возьмёт данные из локального файла для конкретного URL, но сами данные в где-то там в DNS для данного URL уже изменились с того момента, как были записаны данные в локальный файл windows ?
Ведь по этим данным я уже не смог сконнектится с сервером.

Comment: 1) это правильное поведение 2)Если данные DNS меняются, то следует ждать несколько часов или даже дней, пока не обновятся кеши. DNS не сделан для того, что бы его меняли каждые пять минут

Comment: @user7860670, я имел ввиду, что предположим, я первый раз делаю запрос на google.ru и соответвенно Windows записывает файлы куда то в локальные файлы о соответствии URL и IP адресов. Теперь предположим, что второй запрос я делаю через 6 месяцев, и за это время на DNS уже поменялась информация, а функция getaddrinfo при второй запросе все равно будет брать данные из локального файла ?

Comment: Нет, кэш же протухает. Если приспичело, то его можно и руками сбросить. flushdns или как-то так

Comment: По п.2 — а он и берет часть данных из `hosts`, кстати говоря :)